# I have filed for the same exact patten

Tags: patent-infringement

While waiting on for actual patent title.
We have gone further and have full working App. Bug free and API friendly cross platform.

Here what I find challanig!'
You have the utility pattent. but no product out as far as I have searched..
NOW California lottery just realeesd the 2.0 update. The bar code scan for submitting 2nd chance.

Works beautifully. It Scans less then a scan. I just submitted over 100 tix in less then 10 minutes.

Now who has the legal right for this product or the procedure
In US PATENT law ??!!!

Comment: Was your patent filed before someone else started using it? Do you mean by "title" issuance under your name?

Comment: The filing date(s) will be important here as well. Are the patent(s) being prosecuted as pre-AIA or AIA? You'll need to provide a lot more details (including a patent/application number) if you want a detailed answer.